# How to install bosh-lite cf-release and cf-mysql-release

Tags: cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

I've got a local bosh-lite setup and thigs look good:

```
$ bosh deployments
Acting as user 'admin' on 'Bosh Lite Director'

+-----------+------------+--------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Name      | Release(s) | Stemcell(s)                                      | Cloud Config |
+-----------+------------+--------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| cf-warden | cf/226     | bosh-warden-boshlite-ubuntu-trusty-go_agent/3126 | none         |
+-----------+------------+--------------------------------------------------+--------------+

Deployments total: 1
```

But when I try to install cf-mysql-release I run into a problem with a missing bootstrap template.  Here are the steps I'm taking:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-mysql-release.git
$ cd cf-mysql-release/
$ bosh upload release releases/cf-mysql-24.yml
$ ./bosh-lite/make_manifest
$ bosh deploy
Acting as user 'admin' on deployment 'cf-warden-mysql' on 'Bosh Lite Director'
Getting deployment properties from director...
Unable to get properties list from director, trying without it...
Cannot get current deployment information from director, possibly a new deployment
Please review all changes carefully

Deploying
---------
Are you sure you want to deploy? (type 'yes' to continue): yes

Director task 21
  Started unknown
  Started unknown > Binding deployment. Done (00:00:00)

  Started preparing deployment
  Started preparing deployment > Binding releases. Done (00:00:00)
  Started preparing deployment > Binding existing deployment. Done (00:00:00)
  Started preparing deployment > Binding resource pools. Done (00:00:00)
  Started preparing deployment > Binding stemcells. Done (00:00:00)
  Started preparing deployment > Binding templates. Failed: Can't find template `bootstrap' (00:00:00)

Error 190012: Can't find template `bootstrap'

Task 21 error

For a more detailed error report, run: bosh task 21 --debug
```

And here is (what I hope is) the relevant information from there:

```
$ bosh task 21 --debug
...
D, [2015-12-04 22:04:29 #19024] [task:141] DEBUG -- DirectorJobRunner: SENT: hm.director.alert {"id":"9dc7765a-8f5c-44e9-8854-44fb29ffae72","severity":3,"title":"director - error during update deployment","summary":"Error during update deployment for 'cf-warden-mysql' against Director '3606f4d1-c2f8-48bc-913d-b5a4012e81ec': #<Bosh::Director::DeploymentUnknownTemplate: Can't find template `bootstrap'>","created_at":1449266669}
E, [2015-12-04 22:04:29 #19024] [task:141] ERROR -- DirectorJobRunner: Can't find template `bootstrap'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bosh-director-1.3126.0/lib/bosh/director/deployment_plan/template.rb:29:in `bind_models'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bosh-director-1.3126.0/lib/bosh/director/deployment_plan/release_version.rb:62:in `block in bind_templates'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bosh-director-1.3126.0/lib/bosh/director/deployment_plan/release_version.rb:60:in `each_value'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bosh-director-1.3126.0/lib/bosh/director/deployment_plan/release_version.rb:60:in `bind_templates'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bosh-director-1.3126.0/lib/bosh/director/deployment_plan/assembler.rb:283:in `block in bind_templates'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bosh-director-1.3126.0/lib/bosh/director/deployment_plan/assembler.rb:282:in `each'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bosh-director-1.3126.0/lib/bosh/director/deployment_plan/assembler.rb:282:in `bind_templates'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bosh-director-1.3126.0/lib/bosh/director/deployment_plan/planner_factory.rb:176:in `block in run_prepare_step'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bosh-director-1.3126.0/lib/bosh/director/deployment_plan/planner_factory.rb:195:in `block in track_and_log'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bosh-director-1.3126.0/lib/bosh/director/event_log.rb:97:in `call'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bosh-director-1.3126.0/lib/bosh/director/event_log.rb:97:in `advance_and_track'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bosh-director-1.3126.0/lib/bosh/director/event_log.rb:50:in `track'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bosh-director-1.3126.0/lib/bosh/director/deployment_plan/planner_factory.rb:193:in `track_and_log'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bosh-director-1.3126.0/lib/bosh/director/deployment_plan/planner_factory.rb:175:in `run_prepare_step'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bosh-director-1.3126.0/lib/bosh/director/deployment_plan/planner_factory.rb:96:in `bind_vms'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bosh-director-1.3126.0/lib/bosh/director/deployment_plan/planner_factory.rb:39:in `planner'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bosh-director-1.3126.0/lib/bosh/director/jobs/update_deployment.rb:31:in `block in perform'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bosh-director-1.3126.0/lib/bosh/director/lock_helper.rb:13:in `block in with_deployment_lock'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bosh-director-1.3126.0/lib/bosh/director/lock.rb:56:in `lock'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bosh-director-1.3126.0/lib/bosh/director/lock_helper.rb:13:in `with_deployment_lock'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bosh-director-1.3126.0/lib/bosh/director/jobs/update_deployment.rb:25:in `perform'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bosh-director-1.3126.0/lib/bosh/director/job_runner.rb:108:in `perform_job'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bosh-director-1.3126.0/lib/bosh/director/job_runner.rb:31:in `block in run'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bosh_common-1.3126.0/lib/common/thread_formatter.rb:49:in `with_thread_name'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bosh-director-1.3126.0/lib/bosh/director/job_runner.rb:31:in `run'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bosh-director-1.3126.0/lib/bosh/director/jobs/base_job.rb:10:in `perform'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/resque-1.25.2/lib/resque/job.rb:227:in `perform'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/resque-1.25.2/lib/resque/worker.rb:250:in `perform'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/resque-1.25.2/lib/resque/worker.rb:189:in `block in work'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/resque-1.25.2/lib/resque/worker.rb:166:in `loop'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/resque-1.25.2/lib/resque/worker.rb:166:in `work'
/var/vcap/packages/director/gem_home/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bosh-director-1.3126.0/bin/bosh-director-worker:76:in `<top (required)>'
/var/vcap/packages/director/bin/bosh-director-worker:16:in `load'
/var/vcap/packages/director/bin/bosh-director-worker:16:in `<main>'
D, [2015-12-04 22:04:29 #19024] [task:141] DEBUG -- DirectorJobRunner: (0.000112s) SELECT NULL
D, [2015-12-04 22:04:29 #19024] [task:141] DEBUG -- DirectorJobRunner: (0.000052s) BEGIN
D, [2015-12-04 22:04:29 #19024] [task:141] DEBUG -- DirectorJobRunner: (0.000196s) UPDATE "tasks" SET "state" = 'error', "timestamp" = '2015-12-04 22:04:29.294817+0000', "description" = 'create deployment', "result" = 'Can''t find template `bootstrap''', "output" = '/var/vcap/store/director/tasks/141', "checkpoint_time" = '2015-12-04 22:04:29.042357+0000', "type" = 'update_deployment', "username" = 'admin' WHERE ("id" = 141)
D, [2015-12-04 22:04:29 #19024] [task:141] DEBUG -- DirectorJobRunner: (0.000560s) COMMIT
I, [2015-12-04 22:04:29 #19024] []  INFO -- DirectorJobRunner: Task took 0.255747541 seconds to process.

Task 21 error
```

I've tried reinstalling bosh-lite and cf-warden in 10 different ways, with different versions of ruby and gems and I still can't get past this problem. I've also tried different different releases of cf-mysql-release.  I was using this blog post as my reference: https://vyatkins.wordpress.com/2015/02/25/how-to-deploy-mysql-service-in-cloud-foundry-on-your-local/

My current version of ruby was installed from sources.

Additional relevant info from my last pass:

```
$ ruby -v 
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin15]
$ gem -v
2.5.0
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.11.1
BuildVersion:   15B42
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is you're generating the manifest against the `develop` branch of the repo, which introduces a `bootstrap` job/template, but you've uploaded `v24` of the release, which doesn't have that job yet.

Compare:

- develop jobs: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-mysql-release/tree/develop/jobs
- v24 jobs: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-mysql-release/tree/v24/jobs

You should first checkout the `v24` tag before running `bosh-lite/make_manifest`.